# Why is my project installing the wrong Angular version?

Tags: angularjs, angular, npm

My project doesn't seem to have the latest Angular code but I'm not sure why.

This is in my [package.json](https://github.com/dancancro/rangle-started/blob/master/package.json#L47-L52)

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
```

This is a function in my `node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.js` that I need to patch to fix [this problem](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/10595/commits/3f689321dc0f5c1c428138eb7aa3889bd58a04e9)

```
function componentModuleUrl(reflector, type, cmpMetadata) {
    if (cpl.isStaticSymbol(type)) {
        return staticTypeModuleUrl(type);
    }
    if (isPresent(cmpMetadata.moduleId)) {
        var moduleId = cmpMetadata.moduleId;
        var scheme = getUrlScheme(moduleId);
        return isPresent(scheme) && scheme.length > 0 ? moduleId :
            "package:" + moduleId + MODULE_SUFFIX;
    }
    return reflector.importUri(type);
}
```

This is the same function (in TypeScript) in the [Angular GitHub repository](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts#L762-L780)

```
function componentModuleUrl(
    reflector: ReflectorReader, type: Type<any>, cmpMetadata: Component): string {
  if (cpl.isStaticSymbol(type)) {
    return staticTypeModuleUrl(type);
  }

  const moduleId = cmpMetadata.moduleId;

  if (typeof moduleId === 'string') {
    const scheme = getUrlScheme(moduleId);
    return scheme ? moduleId : `package:${moduleId}${MODULE_SUFFIX}`;
  } else if (moduleId !== null && moduleId !== void 0) {
    throw new Error(
        `moduleId should be a string in "${stringify(type)}". See <shortened link that stackoverflow does not allow> for more information.\n` +
        `If you're using Webpack you should inline the template and the styles, see <shortened link that stackoverflow does not allow>`);
  }

  return reflector.importUri(type);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right version. You just need to select the correct tag

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0/modules/%40angular/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts#L736
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how to do that. But I know these guesses don't work `"@angular/common": "2.0.0#2.0.0"`, `"@angular/common": "git://angular/angular.git#2.0.0"`, `"@angular/common": "git://github.com/angular/angular.git#2.0.0"`

Comment: Nevermind. This worked: `"@angular/common": "angular/angular#2.0.0"`